# Is Implementation defined behaviour an undefined behaviour

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I have opened a C99 standard. Ch. 4 "Conformance", p.2 says the following:

*If a ‘‘shall’’ or **‘‘shall not’’ requirement** that appears outside of a constraint is violated, the behavior is **undefined**. [...]*

Below, in p. 5 we see the following:

*[...] (2) It **shall not** produce output **dependent on** any unspecified, undefined, or **implementation-defined behavior**, and shall not exceed any
minimum implementation limit.*

This to me seems to suggest that implementation-defined behaviour is undefined behaviour, because a program "shall not" depend on implementation-defined behaviour.

Now, I have two questions:

- What does "outside of constraint", mentioned in Ch.4 p. 2 mean? Does this apply to the current situation and why? (I am not good complicated english sentences so pointing out what "constraint" there is would be much appreciated).
- Is implementation behaviour undefined after all? Yes/no, why?

Comment: I haven't read the actual thing so I don't know full context about what it's talking about, but it likely just means that thing should be the same for all implementations. It doesn't mean that implementation defined behavior = undefined behavior. But I think it does mean in this specific case that if this rule about not being implementation defined (or undefined or unspecified) is violated then there's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 ahh yes the context of that seems to suggest it is meant for implementations. That makes it clearer

Comment: Wait, no, actually it was clearly talking about "strictly conforming program".

Comment: What I'm trying to say is in this specific case I guess implementation defined = undefined as it's specifically not supposed to be implementation-defined (this is a constraint, and according to your quote a constraint violation means undefined behavior). Otherwise however they do not necessarily mean the same thing.

Comment: Since "implementation defined" is not defined in the standard, it is "undefined" in the sense of the standard in my eyes. But in contrary to "random behavior" that is undefined as well, it is defined by the implementation.

Comment: @thebusybee: “Implementation defined” is defined in the C standard; it is defined in C 2018 3.4.1: “implementation-defined behavior / unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made”. This is clearly different from “undefined”; “undefined” means “… this document imposes no requirements” (C 2018 3.4.3). Implementation-defined behavior has a requirement, that the implementation document the choice made, so it is not undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh yes, you're right. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, implementation defined behaviour is not undefined behaviour.

Paragraph 5 refers to **strictly** conforming programs:

> 5. A *strictly conforming program* shall use only those features of the language and library
>    specified in this International Standard. <sup>2)</sup> It shall not produce output dependent on any
>    unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior, and shall not exceed any
>    minimum implementation limit.

Paragraph 7 and its footnote explain that there are 2 levels of conformance:

> 7. A *conforming program* is one that is acceptable to a conforming implementation. <sup>4)</sup>

> <sub>4) Strictly conforming programs are intended to be maximally portable among conforming
> implementations. Conforming programs may depend upon nonportable features of a conforming
> implementation.</sub>

Program with implementation defined behaviour is simply conforming program, but not strictly conforming program.

Comment: The Standard also allows for the possibility that implementations may, as a form of "Conforming Language Extension", specify how they will process constructs that the Standard characterizes as invoking Undefined Behavior, and that correct programs that are conforming but not strictly programming may exploit such extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation defined behaviour is really different from Undefined Behaviour.

- implementation defined behaviour means that an implementation must choose one of the possible behaviours. For example a `char` is allowed to be either signed or unsigned, no other possible choice.
- undefined behaviour means that the standard sets no restriction on the possible behaviour, from the expected one to an immediate program crash. Furthermore, an optimizing compiler is free to assume that a program contains no UB. That means that if you invoke Undefined Behaviour in a branch of a conditional (`if`) the compiler may optimize out the whole branch and the test.

Answer (score 1):

> This to me seems to suggest that implementation-defined behaviour is undefined behaviour  /--/
> Is implementation behaviour undefined after all? Yes/no, why?

No, since the terms are not defined there. They are even formal terms found in chapter 3, terms:

> **3.4.3**
> **undefined behavior**
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
> for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

> **3.4.4**
> **unspecified behavior**
> use of an unspecified value, or other behavior where this International Standard provides two or more possibilities and imposes no further requirements on which is chosen in any instance

> **3.4.1**
> **implementation-defined behavior**
> unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made

---

> because a program "shall not" depend on implementation-defined behaviour.

You are reading the definition of a *strictly conforming program*. That is, a program which contains no extensions and no poorly-defined behavior. This term is mostly just meaningful in the definition of a *conforming implementation*, meaning standard compliant compiler. A compiler is conforming if it accepts any strictly conforming program.

---

> What does "outside of constraint", mentioned in Ch.4 p. 2 mean?

The standard has certain extra important sections called constraints - also a formal term which you can find in chapter 3:

> **3.8**
> **constraint**
> restriction, either syntactic or semantic, by which the exposition of language elements is to be interpreted

Compilers are required to omit diagnostic messages in case a program breaks any constraints or syntax rules. For example if we read the definition of lets say the additive operators 6.5.6, it goes:

> **Constraints**
> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type.

So if I am writing code with two structs as `mystruct1 + mystruct2`, that's a *constraint violation*, since my operands are neither arithmetic nor pointer types. (It is also undefined behavior since it violates a 'shall' requirement of the standard.)

Answer (score -1):

The C Standard uses the term "shall" in a way different from most standards.  The clear intention is that a program that violates a constraint cannot be a Strictly Conforming Program, but if a program that isn't strictly conforming violates a constraint, all that means is that the Standard waives jurisdiction over how an implementations process the program, so as to allow them to process it in whatever manner would best serve their customers.  The Standard makes no attempt to forbid implementations from processing such constructs in ways hostile to their customers, because they thought compiler writers would seek to make their compilers maximally appealing to programmers.

I suppose one could interpret the "shall" in the definition of a strictly conforming program the same way as it would be used elsewhere, implying that violation of a constraint even within that definition is merely a waiver of jurisdiction, but that would render the term "Strictly Conforming C Program" just as meaningless as the term "Conforming C Program", and even more meaningless than the term "Conforming C Implementation(*), which would seem rather silly.

(*) The "one program rule" specifies that a Conforming C implementation must correctly processes in Standard-defined fashion at least one possibly-contrived-and-useless program that exercises the translation limits given in N1570 5.2.4.1, but nothing an implementation does with any other source text could render it non-conforming.  The published Rationale makes clear an intention that an implementation's ability to process useful programs be regarded as a "quality of implementation" issue, rather than a conformance issue.